# STM32: I2C slave without enabled clock stretching feature

Tags: stm32, i2c, master-slave, cortex-m

I have to implement on a STM32L053 an I2C slave to read/write some arbitrary bytes of memory on the slave uC and the requirement is, that it should also work for I2C masters, which are not support clock stretching (`NOSTRETCH=1`).

I found a good example at:

- https://drolliblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/04/stm32l031x6-slave-transmitter-and-receiver/

And here is the implementation of this article:

- https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/tree/master/sys/arm/stm32l031x6/i2c_test

This implementation works for me without problems for the read operation @100KHz data rate, but the write operations from the master are just working properly about 50%. Sometimes the written bytes are correct and sometimes not...

The difference between this example and my environment is, despite the uC are a bit different but still STM32L0 deviates, I have to use a quite lower sysclock due to the fact, I also have to fulfill another requirement for low power consumption. My uC is running at 4Mhz and the one in the example is running at 32Mhz.
Therefore, I am afraid, that I am due to my slow sysclock unable to read the incoming write data from the master fast enough within the ISR, before the next incoming data is received...

Can someone please give me a hint if it is possible to implement such a No-Clock-Stretching-I2C-Slave with my 4Mhz environment at all, and if yes, what can I do to get the write operations also working reliable?

Here is the description of the reference manual for the `NOSTRETCH=1` setting:

- https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/2f/b9/c6/34/28/29/42/d2/DM00095744.pdf/files/DM00095744.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00095744.pdf

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the implementation of the read/write functions and the I2C ISR:

```
volatile unsigned char i2c_mem[256];     /* contains data, which read or written */
volatile unsigned char i2c_idx;          /* the current index into i2c_mem */
volatile unsigned char i2c_is_write_idx; /* write state */

volatile uint16_t i2c_total_irq_cnt;
volatile uint16_t i2c_TXIS_cnt;
volatile uint16_t i2c_RXNE_cnt;


void i2c_mem_reset_write(void)
{
  i2c_is_write_idx = 1;  
}

void i2c_mem_init(void)
{
  i2c_idx = 0;
  i2c_mem_reset_write();
}

void i2c_mem_set_index(unsigned char value)
{
  i2c_idx = value;
  i2c_is_write_idx = 0;
}

void i2c_mem_write_via_index(unsigned char value)
{
  i2c_mem[i2c_idx++] = value;
}

unsigned char i2c_mem_read(void)
{
  i2c_mem_reset_write();
  i2c_idx++;
  return i2c_mem[i2c_idx];
}

void i2c_mem_write(unsigned char value)
{
  if ( i2c_is_write_idx != 0 )
  {
    i2c_mem_set_index(value);
  }
  else
  {
    i2c_is_write_idx = 0;
    i2c_mem_write_via_index(value);
  }
}

void __attribute__ ((interrupt, used)) I2C1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  unsigned long isr = I2C1->ISR;

  i2c_total_irq_cnt ++;

  if ( isr & I2C_ISR_TXIS )
  {
    i2c_TXIS_cnt++;
    I2C1->TXDR = i2c_mem_read();
  }
  else if ( isr & I2C_ISR_RXNE )
  {
    i2c_RXNE_cnt++;
    i2c_mem_write(I2C1->RXDR);
    I2C1->ISR |= I2C_ISR_TXE;           // allow overwriting the TCDR with new data
    I2C1->TXDR = i2c_mem[i2c_idx];
  }
  else if ( isr & I2C_ISR_STOPF )
  {
    I2C1->ICR = I2C_ICR_STOPCF;
    I2C1->ISR |= I2C_ISR_TXE;           // allow overwriting the TCDR with new data
    I2C1->TXDR = i2c_mem[i2c_idx];
    i2c_mem_reset_write();
  }
  else if ( isr & I2C_ISR_NACKF )
  {
    I2C1->ICR = I2C_ICR_NACKCF;
    I2C1->ISR |= I2C_ISR_TXE;           // allow overwriting the TCDR with new data
    I2C1->TXDR = i2c_mem[i2c_idx];
    i2c_mem_reset_write();
  }
  else if ( isr & I2C_ISR_ADDR )
  {
    /* not required, the addr match interrupt is not enabled */
    I2C1->ICR = I2C_ICR_ADDRCF;
    I2C1->ISR |= I2C_ISR_TXE;           // allow overwriting the TCDR with new data
    I2C1->TXDR = i2c_mem[i2c_idx];
    i2c_mem_reset_write();
  }

  /* if at any time the addr match is set, clear the flag */
  /* not sure, whether this is required */
  if ( isr & I2C_ISR_ADDR )
  {
    I2C1->ICR = I2C_ICR_ADDRCF;
  }

}
```

Comment: Does it work with 32 MHz *on your hardware*? Which gcc version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I just tried 32 MHz and could not reproduce any write error.

Comment: I am using the new STM32CubeIDE which uses as gcc: arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (GNU Tools for STM32 7-2018-q2-update.20190328-1800) 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907]

Comment: Strange thing: I tried another setting for the I2C clock source and changed it from `RCC_I2C1CLKSOURCE_PCLK1` (which was the 4MHz MSI) to `RCC_I2C1CLKSOURCE_HSI` (which runs at 16MHz) and seems to work at 4MHz sysclock. Could it be, that the I2C peripheral needs more that 4Mhz clock for this operation mode?

Comment: Did you adjust `I2C1->TIMINGR` when changing the clock speed? What values do you use at each clock speed?

Comment: I used the `TIMINGR` setting generated from STM32CubeMX. For 4 MHz I took `0x00100E16` and for 32MHz I used and since I forgot to revert it back, I still use `0x00707CBB` (for my current setup which seems to "work" with 4MHz MSI sysclock + 16 MHz HSI I2C Clock source). Can you imagine why this new timing setting improves the situation?

Comment: I can't wrap my head around all the timing formulas presented in the reference manual, but apparently it depends on the required data hold and setup times, which in turn depend on the rise and fall times, which depend on the electrical characteristics of the parts used... Calculating `TIMINGR` in CubeMX with Rise Time = 1000 and Fall Time = 300 yields **`0x20100405`** @4MHz. Adjusting the values in the *examples of timing settings* table in the reference manual for 4MHz gives **`0x00420F13`**. Note that the blog author gets the prescaler adjustment wrong, IMO it should be `0x70420F13` @ 32MHz.

Comment: Thank you for your time berendi, I very appreciate your helping comments. Looks like there is a good chance to implement such a non-clock-stretching I2C slave as I intended. I try to dig deeper into that timing topic, looks very promising :)

Comment: I tested some combinations of the timing register and found out, that the positive change of no communication errors anymore only came from changing the peripheral clock source for the I2C from sysclock (4MHz MSI) to HSI (16MHz). Does someone have an idea why workaround works? Perhaps an undocumented hardware glitch/limitation?